# How to create a google map from user input in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making an HTML file which basically takes the latitude and longitude coordinates from the user and then prints out a google map with that cordinates. I have the following code. The errors I get is google is not defined in "var map=new..." and the map does not load. There is a div file contains the map. But it only shows up in gray. And whenever I interact with that blank map I get so many errors. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Find My Phone</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2196F3">
<p style="font-size:150%; text-align:center">This is the extension for the   app FindMyPhone. In this site, you can view the coordinates where your phone was traced on a map</p>
Latitude:
<input type="number" step="any" id="Lat"/> <br>
Longitude:
<input type="number" step="any" id="Lng"/> <br>
<button>Submit</button>
<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:500px; color:#9E9E9E">
</div>
<script async defer 
    src= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyAPIKey&callback=NewMap">
</script>
<script>
document.querySelector('button')
.addEventListener('click',NewMap());
function NewMap() {
 var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
 var Latitude = document.getElementById('Lat');
 var Longitude = document.getElementById('Lng');
 var mapOptions = {
     center: document.getElementById(Latitude, Longitude),
     zoom:15
 }
  var Map = new google.maps.Map (mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what the output looks like:
[image: The gray color represents the map]

This is the error code that I get without interacting with the blank map:
[image: That is the error that I get without interacting with the blank map]

This is the error code that I get upon interacting with the blank map:[![Lots of error code and as you continue to move your mouse outside the div which contains the map,the errors stack up][3]][3]

[![The errors stack up][3]][3]

[image: Lots of errors]

Comment: Why `<script async defer` there?

Comment: @Div That's how google recommends it

Comment: @RobinDorbell Can you provide me a link of that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: @RobinDorbell Thanks!

Comment: I see an unwanted space here: `api/js?  key=`, also you should edit your post to remove the API key.

Answer (score 1):

Those map options are wrong, you're trying to create a center by getting the element with id Longitude and Latitude.

Try without the options or at least the `.value` from the elements.

```
function NewMap() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var Latitude = document.getElementById('Lat').value;
    var Longitude = document.getElementById('Lng').value;
    var mapOptions = {
        center:{ lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude },
        zoom:15
    }

    var Map = new google.maps.Map (mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
```

I've checked your link so google should be defined, a word of advice though; You're publicly showing your API-key to the google maps api.

You're also running the function instantaneously here:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',NewMap());
```

because you're using `NewMap()` which is a call to a function instead of a reference to it - which makes it run before google has been initialized. Change this to:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',NewMap);
```

Comment: i am sorry sir. my mistake

Comment: what do you mean by publicly showing API key to the google maps API?

Comment: Your API-key to the google maps API is the part of the address from which you get the google script. It says `key=$$$$$$` in the link. So now anyone who sees this post can use your key.

Comment: Sorry about that. But btw As i interact with the google map which is black(I don't know the reason for this) I get a bunch of errors As seen in last pic

Comment: That's probably because the map isn't loaded correctly. Have you tried the fixes I recommended?

Comment: I tried the fixes you recommended but it still does not lad the map

Comment: It returns an error of js?key=APIKEY&callback=NewMap:37 InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number_.ib @ js?key=AIzaSyB0ML3EyR_nt7wq3sEotf3PYi7wOCbmq3E&callback=NewMap:37

Comment: It says that the input you have inside your Long/Lat inputs is invalid.